# Specify dynamically where to output ajax success result for multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two questions:

1. How can I create a second form in the same page and ajax handle the right form depending on which submit button got clicked?
2. Now let's suppose I have multiple forms in the same page. I want to change where the output goes depending on which submit button is clicked.

Source code:

**Ajax:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('post.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
<form id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="a"><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="results"></div> <!-- post.php output goes here.-->
<!-- until here everything is working fine -->
<!-- now if I want to add a second form I don't know what id I should use -->
```

Comment: What is the form argument that you get in the submitHandler? Is that the from DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class on your forms to bind to, and then each form can have an element that holds the output id which you select -

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".myforms").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('post.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
                    var output = $(form).data('output');
                    $("#"+output).html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

html

```
<form class="myforms" action="" method="POST" data-output="results1">
    <input type="text" name="a"><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="results1"></div>    

<form class="myforms" action="" method="POST" data-output="results2">
    <input type="text" name="a"><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="results2"></div>  

<form class="myforms" action="" method="POST" data-output="results3">
    <input type="text" name="a"><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="results3"></div>
```

Comment: now all submit buttons work as part of the fist form, when I click submit on whatever submit button, it uses the first form.
BTW, the data-output solved my second question.

Comment: I think I should give each form a different class, but how can I change the javascript function to accept a dynamic class name ?